# Retrieve HTML5 SessionStorage

Tags: c#

Say I want to retrieve the session storage for a website, how would I go about it and is it even possible? I have attached a photo from the Chrome DevTools and highlighted an example of the kind of data field that I wish to capture.

My goal is to load an external website and capture a specific session storage key value. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any clues about this online.

[Google Chrome DevTools example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGGI0.png)

Comment: You can't access that value unless you can get code to run on `https://www.google.com/`. The Storage API works on same origin permission, same as most APIs.

Answer (score -1):

Nope! due a very security mistake if it can be possible.

All site data (browser cookies, storage) belongs to site itself, it is great!

If you want expose some data to other site, you should consider store them to a server and all sites which wants consume that data makes a request to server.

Comment: I don't see any problem doing what OP asked about - " load an external website and capture a specific session storage key value". You seem to be answering "how to perform x-site scripting on my webpage hosting IFrame of an external site" but there is no indication that OP is looking for that. There are plenty of examples of obtaining information from a page rendered in a local browsers by C# code (using Selenium or simply hosting the browser inside the app). You may want to [edit] the answer to clarify what is the question you are answering.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov think about tokens, whereas kept to localStorage, or cookies, its a common approach, imagine some one access some website, and can stole token and refresh token? my answer points to third sites should not have accesses to nothing, regardless not sensible data. If there need to consume it server is who handle it.